# last login on jumphost with proxycommand

Tags: linux, session, ssh, user-management, ssh-tunnel

I would like to find out when which user has last logged in on our system, so that I can delete users who have not used the system for longer than 90 days.

For this I look at our jumphost (Linux RHEL 6 or 7), through which all the accesses should happen. 
the `lastlog` command is very handy and would suit my needs perfectly. BUT if people use the `ProxyCommand` or a ssh tunnel, the lastlog does not record the logging, and I will not know if the users have been on the system.

examples would be:

```
ProxyCommand ssh username@192.168.190.11 'netcat hostname 22'
```

or

```
ssh -f username@192.168.190.11 -L 123.123.123.123:2001 -N
```

Is there a way to see who when users last logged-in even though they use ssh tunnels via the proxy?

Thanks for the help!